# Iinstalling old plugins from git repo with Phonegap 3.6?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I was using cordova-plugin-geolocation in my phonegap project successfully but I've had to re-install some plugins because sometimes phonegap forgets about them.

When I've come to re-install cordova-plugin-geolocation it seems there is a new release which is no longer compatible with Phonegap 3.6.

There are instructions on the github site explaining how to install the old version with cordova:

"Older versions of cordova can still install via the deprecated id ( stale 0.3.12 )"

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.geolocation
```

but nothing about how to do it with Phonegap. (I Have tried the cordova command but it does not work)

How can I re-install this plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the release you want to install

from github:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation#<release>
```

from NPM

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation@<release>
```

where `<release>` is one on the releases on 
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation/releases

example

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation@0.3.12
```